# ExpressJS Installation

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

so I did npm install express according to the tutorial, after installing express I did

```
'express --version'
```

and express is not in my path. I am wondering what I did wrong or is there any way to test if express works on my OS.

Comment: install express via npm?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you use `npm install express` or `npm install express -g`?

The second command is what you should use if you want to use the express program from the command line. The `-g` option installs the library globally.

The first command will just install the library in a `node_modules` subfolder, and you would need to explicitly locate the program before using it, eg. `node ./node_modules/express/bin/express` (I'm not sure if that's the right command, just an example).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding the path to the npm's bin directory to your PATH?

```
export PATH="/usr/local/share/npm/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Create a directory**
and execute:
$ npm install -g express

**If you want to generate an application with EJS, Stylus etc simply execute:**

$ express --sessions --css stylus --ejs yourapp